# R: changing String values to NA, getting coercion error

Tags: r

I've got a dataset called `data` that looks like this:

```
  Year  Population
1 2005  3000  
2 2006  4000 
3 2007  5000
4 2008  6000
5 2009  NP
6 2010  NP
7 2011  NP
8 2012  6000
9 2013  3000
```

I want to get the average of the count column, but since NP is not a numeric value I want to convert it to NA. I've used the following code:

```
data %>% mutate(Count = as.numeric(Count))
```

However I get an error message saying that NAs have been introduced by coercion. How can I convert all of the values to numeric and avoid getting this error?

Comment: It is not an error message, just a warning

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error, just a warning message.

**1)** We can wrap with `suppressWarnings`

```
data$Count <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(data$Count)))
```

e.g.

```
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b')
suppressWarnings(as.numeric(v1))
#[1]  1  2  3 NA NA
```

The most direct method of converting is to apply the `as.numeric` without any other manipulations.  The `warning` here is a friendly message.

**2)**  If we want to convert to `numeric` without getting the warnings, another option would be to replace the `NP` to `NA

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
      mutate(Count = as.numeric(na_if(Count, 'NP')))
```

**3)** Or another option is to `replace` the elements to `NA` based on non-numeric character

```
library(stringr)
data %>% 
    mutate(Count = as.numeric(replace(Count,
           str_detect(Count, '\\D'), NA)))
```

We can get the summarised output within `summarise` or `mutate`

```
data %>%
      mutate(Count = sum(as.numeric(replace(Count, str_detect(Count, '\\D'), NA)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways in which you can do this.

Couple of ways include -

1. Using `grepl` we can turn all the values in `Population` column that has a non-digit character to `NA` and convert it to numeric.

```
df$Population[grepl('\\D', df$Population)] <- NA
df$Population <- as.numeric(df$Population)
df

#  Year Population
#1 2005       3000
#2 2006       4000
#3 2007       5000
#4 2008       6000
#5 2009         NA
#6 2010         NA
#7 2011         NA
#8 2012       6000
#9 2013       3000
```

2. With `parse_number` :

```
df$Population <- readr::parse_number(df$Population)
```

After doing this you can perform all the mathematical operations as usual with `na.rm = TRUE`.

```
mean(df$Population, na.rm = TRUE)
sum(df$Population, na.rm = TRUE)
```